# AWS DMS Task failed with error: Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms, citus

I want to migrate my PostgresDB hosted in Citus cloud service to AWS RDS Aurora Postgres.
I am using AWS DMS service. Have created task but getting following errors:

> Last failure message Last Error Stream Component Fatal error. Task
> error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0
> [reptask/replicationtask.c:2860] [1020101] Error executing source
> loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component
> st_0_QOIS7XIGJDKNPY6RXMGYRLJQHY2P7IQBWIBA5NQ; Stream component
> 'st_0_QOIS7XIGJDKNPY6RXMGYRLJQHY2P7IQBWIBA5NQ' terminated
> [reptask/replicationtask.c:2868] [1020101] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR
> Error Level FATAL

Frankly speaking not able to understand what is wrong here, so any help is appreciated.

cloudwatch logs:

[image]

Comment: Your cloudwatch logs if enabled will provide more information.. Have you checked that

Comment: @Emerson hvae updated my question with cloudwatch logs but from that also I am not able to understand root cause of failure,

Comment: @AshishKarpe have you figured this one out?

Comment: Not sure how but I changed type to Full load it worked so it is not working for ongoing replication Citus Cloud service don't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed type to Full load it worked so it is not working for ongoing replication Citus Cloud service don't support it.

Comment: what do you mean by full load ? where?

Comment: @LumbusterTick probably referring to migration task's type. You can have "migrate existing data" which is described as full load on task overview UI once running. Other options are "migrate & replicate ongoing changes", and "replicate data changes only".

Comment: @LukasLiesis Thanks. Btw ongoing replication needs a peer connection with your database.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error to this using Aurora PostgreSQL v14.5 and AWS DMS.  I was using a DMS Full load + CDC job (using pglogical behind the scenes) to migrate from one table to another (on the same system).

Issue was resolved by rolling back my PostgreSQL version from 14.5 to 13.7.

Answer (score 2):

For Full load task, Select permission for DMS user is enough. But for the CDC (Ongoing replication tasks), superuser permission is required for the DMS user over Database.